# Is there a way to animate table in google slides?

Tags: google-slides

I want the rows to appear one at a time with each click. I could not figure out a way to do that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should have been asked and answered on Web Apps StackExchange and has nothing to do with programmatic interaction with Google Slides

Answer (score 2):

i think it's not possible but there's a trick you can try as mentionned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.powerpoint/Dy209VbcUnk)

> You can copy or cut it, CTRL+ALT+V to paste special and choose EMF or WMF, then ungroup the EMF/WMF twice. Group parts as necessary and animate.

or

> Keep the table as is and cover it with rectangles to match the background. (choose Slide Background Fill in the Shape Fill options)
>
> Animate the rectangles with exit effects to reveal sections of the table;
> entrance effects to hide the sections again.

Comment: That tip is for PowerPoint, not Google Slides.

Comment: Covering it with rectangles works for Google slides as well